# Find duplicate consecutive numbers in a randomly generated array

Tags: c++, arrays, windows

I want to find duplicate numbers in a row (2 in a row, 3 in a row, ...) in a randomly generated array. I can't make it further than this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    const int velikostPolja = 100;
    int a[velikostPolja];
    int y = 0;
    int x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < velikostPolja; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 10;
        cout << a[i];   
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < velikostPolja; i++)
    {       
        if (a[i] == a[i + 1])
            x++;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Two times repated in row: " << x << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hint: sort the array

Comment: You would have access out of bound with `a[i] == a[i + 1]`, as you don't modify the range.

Comment: @RichardCritten, Why would he want to sort the array ?

Comment: @SidS unsorted you have to make multiple passes along the array to find all the duplicates (1st value all the way down, 2nd value all the way 3rd etc).  Sorted the duplicates will be moved next to each other and they can all be found in 1 pass.

Comment: @RichardCritten, He wants to count repeated numbers next to each other, so one pass will do.  He has implemented it for 2 in a row, but not 3+ in a row.

Comment: @Jarod42 but how do i modify the range. Now i am looking if one element in array is same as the next one. So if there are 3 or 4 numbers in a row, it counts like 2. i want it seperated 2x,3x,4x,... like you said i have to modify the range but im struggling.

Comment: I meant that you should do something like that instead `for (int i = 0; i + 1 < velikostPolja; i++) { if (a[i] == a[i + 1])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
int count[velikostPolja] = { 0 };
int c = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < velikostPolja; i++)
{       
    if (a[i] == a[i - 1])
    {
        ++c;
    }
    else
    {
        ++count[c];
        c = 0;
    }
}

for (int i = 1; i < velikostPolja; i++)
{
    if (count[i])
    {
        cout << i + 1 << " times repeated in row: " << count[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

This does not account for any repeats at the end of `a`, though.  I leave that as an exercise for you to do yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You might use:

```
template <typename IT>
std::size_t count_repetition(IT begin, IT end, std::size_t count)
{
    std::size_t res = 0;
    auto it = begin;
    while (it != end) {
        it = std::adjacent_find(it, end);
        if (it == end){
            return res;   
        }
        const auto it2 = std::find_if(it, end, [it](const auto& e) { return e != *it; });
        const auto dist = std::distance(it, it2);
        if (count <= dist) {
            // how to count 2-repetition for {a, a, a, a}
#if 0            
            ++res; // Count only as 1
#else
            res += dist + 1 - count; // count as 3
#endif
        }
        it = it2;
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Xz3P4j)